# Multiple Google Verifications on Same Domain?

Tags: dns, site-verification

I have a domain and I need to verify different services with Google by making a TXT record in my DNS. My company wants to verify their Youtube account with our domain, but there is already a TXT record on our site for another service, I think Google Analytics.

I've heard I shouldn't delete these TXT files but I can't make two for the same host. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Domains support multiple TXT record entries, so adding multiple TXT records to one domain is not a problem for either your domain or Google.

However you need to use a different alias, for example:

- Root Domain will use alias `@` or `leave it blank`
- Sub Domain should be set to the name of the subdomain, if your subdomain is sub.domain.com, write `sub` for the Host.

You can find [more help on Google's Verification](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2716802) Page.

Comment: When I try to add the record with the same host, I get the error `Tried to create resource record set [name='domain.com', type='TXT'] but it already exists`, leading me to believe I can only have one.

Comment: Then you need to contact your DNS provider.

Comment: Looks like it was a quirk and I have to put both entries in one TXT record at my provider. Thanks.

Comment: There you go... that should allow you to get around the problem you have.